# Image only zoom in but not zoom out in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have content page which contain photo. I wanted to add the zoom in and zoom out options however when i tried to add the pinch gesture it is only zoom in but not zoom out? how can I add the zoom out options?

here is my XAML:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="ComplexInstructionApp.ShowProgram"
         Title="dsa">
<ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage.Content>

<Grid>

    <Image x:Name="IMI" Aspect="Fill" 
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
              "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
              "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}" 
/>
</Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

and here is my code:
     public partial class ShowProgram : ContentPage
    {

```
    private double currentScale = 1;
    private double startScale = 1;
    private double xOffset = 0;
    private double yOffset = 0;

    public ShowProgram(string txt)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        switch (txt)
        {
            case "קובני":
                IMI.Source = "Cuben_Expend.png";
                break;

            case "קובני מצומצם":
                IMI.Source = "Cuben_short.png";
                break;
            case "אל איי":
                IMI.Source = "LA_Expend.png";
                break;
            case "אל איי מצומצם":
                IMI.Source = "LA_short.png";
                break;
            case "בצ'אטה":
                IMI.Source = "bachata.png";
                break;
            case "זוק":
                IMI.Source = "zouk.png";
                break;                
        }


        var pinchGesture = new PinchGestureRecognizer();
        pinchGesture.PinchUpdated += (s, e) =>
        {

            if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Started)
            {
                // Store the current scale factor applied to the wrapped user interface element,
                // and zero the components for the center point of the translate transform.
                startScale = Content.Scale;
                Content.AnchorX = 0;
                Content.AnchorY = 0;
            }
            if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Running)
            {
                // Calculate the scale factor to be applied.
                currentScale += (e.Scale - 1) * startScale;
                currentScale = Math.Max(1, currentScale);

                // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
                // so get the X pixel coordinate.
                double renderedX = Content.X + xOffset;
                double deltaX = renderedX / Width;
                double deltaWidth = Width / (Content.Width * startScale);
                double originX = (e.ScaleOrigin.X - deltaX) * deltaWidth;

                // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
                // so get the Y pixel coordinate.
                double renderedY = Content.Y + yOffset;
                double deltaY = renderedY / Height;
                double deltaHeight = Height / (Content.Height * startScale);
                double originY = (e.ScaleOrigin.Y - deltaY) * deltaHeight;

                // Calculate the transformed element pixel coordinates.
                double targetX = xOffset - (originX * Content.Width) * (currentScale - startScale);
                double targetY = yOffset - (originY * Content.Height) * (currentScale - startScale);

                // Apply translation based on the change in origin.
                Content.TranslationX = Clamp1(targetX ,- Content.Width * (currentScale - 1), 0);
                Content.TranslationY = Clamp1(targetY, -Content.Height * (currentScale - 1), 0);

                // Apply scale factor.
                Content.Scale = currentScale;
            }
            if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Completed)
            {
                // Store the translation delta's of the wrapped user interface element.
                xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
                yOffset = Content.TranslationY;
            }
        };
        IMI.GestureRecognizers.Add(pinchGesture);
    }

    public  double Clamp1(double self, double min, double max)
    {
        return Math.Min(max, Math.Max(self, min));
    }







}
```

Comment: Not sure why you are using RelativeLayout constraints in grid but anyway I couldn't reproduce your problem. The map scales in and out

Comment: Could you please provide the API Level of your test device?

Comment: Yuri can you please provide the code example that you tested on?
Elvis my API  Level is 25

Comment: I am using API 23 simulator with your code